# Vue 3 composition test method called by child component event

Tags: vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vitest

My goal is to test that the method `selectVirtualDevices` is called when the child component emits the event.

Parent component

```
<template>
  <ChildComponent
    @select-devices="selectVirtualDevices"
  />
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
  const selectVirtualDevices = (devices) => {
    some other magic happening here
  }
</script
```

Child component

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
  const emit = defineEmits(['selectDevices'])
  const selectedDevices = computed({
    get() {
      return state.selectedDevices
    },
    set(device) {
      emit('selectDevices', devices)
    },
  })
</script
```

Test

```
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Parent from './Parent.vue'
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue'
describe('All Devices', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Parent)

  it('should be mounted', () => {
    expect(wrapper.html()).toBeTruthy()
  })

  it('should call selectVirtualDevices', () => {
    const spy = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'selectVirtualDevices')
    wrapper.findComponent(ChildComponent).vm.$emit('selectDevices')
    
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

The test fails with:

```
AssertionError: expected "selectVirtualDevices" to be called at least once
 ❯ Proxy.methodWrapper ../node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/addMethod.js:57:25
 ❯ apps/line-planning/components/AllDevices.spec.ts:35:16
     33|     wrapper.findComponent(DevicesDataTable).vm.$emit('selectDevices')
     34|     
     35|     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
       |                ^
     36|   })
     37| })
```

What am I doing wrong?